# How can I insert to MongoDB a nested JSON lines

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have an Event Entity for MongoDB like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String event;
    private String messageid;
    private String userid;
    private Properties properties;
    private Context context;
    private String timestamp;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class Properties {
    private String productid;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class Context {
    private String source;

}
```

And I have a JSON file example:

```
{"event": "ProductView", "messageid": "b19ac8bb-7011-482d-aeca-a53b93ef277f", "userid": "user-382", "properties": {"productid": "product-354"}, "context": {"source": "desktop"}}
```

I am listening a Kafka topic and consume the JSON lines to mongoDB but in my collections(named by events) its shown like this:

[My collection data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0NNB.png)

But I don't want those situations; {"source": "mobile-app"} and {"productid": "product-340"} instead I just want the data, not JSON format.

I can't find a code block for my problem. How should I change my Event class or which annotation should I use?